# Variable will not become global

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in a function and I want to call it outside of the function however it says 'Name is not defined'. Please advise on how I can make this variable global.

```
n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 80);
console.log(n)
function randomStarwars(){
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/'+n)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data=> {
        var Name = data.name

    })
}
addEventListener("click", randomStarwars)
console.log(Name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: you must define your variable outside your functions - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [variable scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

The reason you can't access it it's because it's defined inside the `.then()` lambda function and can only be accessed there.

To have it available outside that function you need to declare it outside it:

```
n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 80);
var Name = ""; // Here, for example
console.log(n)
function randomStarwars(){
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/'+n)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data=> {
        Name = data.name; // Remove 'var', because it's already declared
    })
}
addEventListener("click", randomStarwars)
console.log(Name)
```

**Update after your comment:**

You don't see the value in your `console.log` because the value is assigned inside a [Promise](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp), which is never run right when declared.

To `console.log` the `Name` effectively, you need to chain another `.then()` and log it there:

```
n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 80);
var Name = ""; // Here, for example
console.log(n)
function randomStarwars(){
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/'+n)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data=> {
        Name = data.name; // Remove 'var', because it's already declared
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(Name) // This guarantees the value has been set, aside from any errors that might occur before
    })
}
addEventListener("click", randomStarwars)
console.log(Name) // This is executed before the Name is set
```

Comment: Thank you, this is running however when I log the name outside of the function the name appears blank calling inside the function logs the name.

Comment: @LewisRevel see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you must declare Variable before the fetch function

```
var Name = "";
    n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 80);
console.log(n)
function randomStarwars(){
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/'+n)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data=> {
         Name = data.name

    })
}
addEventListener("click", randomStarwars)
console.log(Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable outside your functions:

```
var global_Name; // this is your global variable 

n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 80);
console.log(n)


function randomStarwars(){
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/'+n)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data=> {
        global_Name= data.name // use it without var

    })
}
addEventListener("click", randomStarwars)
console.log(Name)

function2()
{
global_Name =  // use it without var
}

function3()
{
 global_Name = // use it without var
}
```